# supervisor and uWSGI will not work together along with nginx

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, supervisord

I use supervisord for managing tornado with no issuse wnhile using nginx as a load balancer.

I am having severe issues with supervisor and uWSGI with nginx as a load blancer.  I am using bottle as the framework.

when I run the below from the command line and I load a page in FF hitting nginx, all works great.

```
sudo command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --loop gevent --socket 127.0.0.1:8070 --wsgi-file /home/ubuntu/workspace/uwsgiServer.py -b 32768 --master --async 5 --enable-threads --listen 100 --uid root
```

If I place the command line in supervior then I get page not found.

```
uWSGI Error
Python application not found



[program:uwsgi]
#autostart=true
#autorestart=true
#process_name = uwsgi-%(process_num)s
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --loop gevent --socket 127.0.0.1:8070 --wsgi-file /home/ubuntu/workspace//uwsgiServer.py -b 32768 --master --async 5 --enable-threads --listen 100 --uid root
#--port=%(process_num)s
#--log_file_prefix=%(here)s/logs/%(program_name)s-%(process_num)s.log
#numprocs = 1
#numprocs_start = 8070
```

Here are the relevant portions of the nginx.conf file:

```
upstream uwsgi_b {
      server 127.0.0.1:8070;
    }


location /u/ {
                       include uwsgi_params;
                       uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                       uwsgi_param Host $http_host;
                       uwsgi_pass uwsgi_b;
                 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might probably add some more params to supervisord config, like --pp (python path) to the uwsgi command, and maybe some environment variables:

```
[program:uwsgi]
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi 
    --loop gevent 
    --socket 127.0.0.1:8070 
    --wsgi-file uwsgiServer.py 
    --buffer-size 32768 --master --async 5 --enable-threads --listen 100 --uid root 
    --pp /home/ubuntu/workspace/

autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=ENV_VAR='var'
user=root # or other
group=root # or other
directory=/home/ubuntu/workspace/
umask=022
```

**EDIT**: Removed Django-specific settings

Comment: Hi,  Its not a django app.  There is not static directory.

Comment: Ops, sorry, just looked at one of my configs. Did you try adding --pp to the command?